# ionic serve cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'

Tags: cordova, angular, npm, ionic2

i have just started ionic2 :

```
$ npm install -g ionic cordova
$ ionic start cutePuppyPics --v2
$ cd cutePuppyPics
$ ionic serve
```

i have this error : cannot find module 'reflect-metadata'

```
$ ionic info 
 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v7.7.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

i try also `npm update -g` , but not work 
`npm -v` : 2.15.11
`ionic -v` 2.2.1

Comment: i  do now : npm install npm@latest -g and npm -v : 4.4.1 now,
and still 'ionic serve ' not working

Comment: i also remove the angular-cli and reinstal using :  npm install -g angular-cli
and still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open your project folder
Open Package.json and add "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",

- run npm install on the folder
  --> ionic is no longer adding reflect-metadata to the package.json

Comment: you should also do 'npm rebuild node-sass'

Answer (score 3):

@Kishore Kumar 's Answer was correct but you need to do an npm rebuild after that.. So

in the Ionic Project, open:

> package.json

Add this in it:

```
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
```

Then run this on console:
`npm install`

and Then run this: `npm rebuild`

Ready to run `ionic serve` to see your app ;)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted */dist* folder, then it works